# CSV file without enclosure for space in string in PHP

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I must generate a CSV with PHP to import it on a delivery optimization software.

This software required that header row matches a defined pattern :

```
tournée,véhicule,livré,type arrêt,date,heure,référence,nom,voie,complément,code postal,ville,pays,lat,lng,téléphone,email,commentaire,libellés,durée destination,référence visite,horaire début 1,horaire fin 1,horaire début 2,horaire fin 2,priorité,libellés visite,durée visite,répéter plages horaires,référence collecte,quantité,opération,codes barres,sans visite,durée client
```

But when I use fputcsv, the spaces in strings are enclosed and I got this (which is not accepted by the software) :

```
tournée,véhicule,livré,"type arrêt",date,heure,référence,nom,voie,complément,"code postal",ville,pays,lat,lng,téléphone,email,commentaire,libellés,"durée destination","référence visite","horaire début 1","horaire fin 1","horaire début 2","horaire fin 2",priorité,"libellés visite","durée visite","répéter plages horaires","référence collecte",quantité,opération,"codes barres","sans visite","durée client"
```

How can I "disable" enclosure for spaces but keep it for characters like comma and semi-colon ?

Comment: _"But when I use fputcsv"_ - so don't use it then? What is stopping you from using `fwrite` to just write this one line at the start of the file, exactly as-is?

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I didn't think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option would probably be to use a CSV library from composer that would give you more configuration options than PHP's built in functions.

However, I was able to find a hacky solution using `fputcsv`.

`fputcsv` allows you to specify the `$enclosure` character (the quotes), however it must be **one** **single-byte** character. So, you *can't* change it to nothing with an empty string (`""`), nor can you set it to `null`. But, if you know the column headers will not change and it's safe to remove the enclosures, then you could set the enclosure character to a character that won't be used anywhere, and then just remove any occurrences of that character.

So, for this example, I chose a character that would almost certainly not be used anywhere else (the `DEL` character) and set that to be used instead of quotes. Rather than having `fputcsv` write directly to a file, I [wrote to memory so that the header string could be saved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417866/451726). From there, I just used `str_replace` to remove the temporary enclosure character. You could then proceed to just use `fwrite` to add the header line to the CSV, and then output the rest of the CSV using `fputcsv` as normal.

```
$headerString = 'tournée,véhicule,livré,type arrêt,date,heure,référence,nom,voie,complément,code postal,ville,pays,lat,lng,téléphone,email,commentaire,libellés,durée destination,référence visite,horaire début 1,horaire fin 1,horaire début 2,horaire fin 2,priorité,libellés visite,durée visite,répéter plages horaires,référence collecte,quantité,opération,codes barres,sans visite,durée client';
$headerColumns = explode(',', $headerString);

$temporaryCharacter = "\x7F";

// output up to 5MB is kept in memory, if it becomes bigger
// it will automatically be written to a temporary file
$tempHeader = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:' . (5 * 1024 * 1024), 'r+');

// Write the header to temporary memory
fputcsv($tempHeader, $headerColumns, ',', $temporaryCharacter);

rewind($tempHeader);

// put it all in a variable
$headerLine = stream_get_contents($tempHeader);

// Remove the enclosure characters
$headerLine = str_replace($temporaryCharacter, '', $headerLine);

echo $headerLine . PHP_EOL;

// fwrite the $headerLine to the file.
```

For your case, it might not even be necessary to use the temporary character; you could probably just leave it with the default quotes for the enclosure, and then use `str_replace('"', '', $headerLine)` to remove the quotes.